# Force 3.5" screen mode in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6

How do I force my new builds in Xcode 4.5 to run in 3.5" screen mode? I don't have a Default-568@2x.png included but the app is still running in full 4" screen mode when testing with that kind of device in the simulator.

Comment: I think it's a bug in the simulator. A real 4" screen device runs it in 3.5". Anyone else confirm?

Comment: I don't think you can 'force' the simulator to only emulate a specific device. Neither can you force someone with a 4-inch iPhone not to use your app... You can change the emulated device in the simulator. Or am I getting your question wrong?

Answer (score 6):

In the simulator, choose Hardware > Device > iPhone (Retina 3.5-inch) *before* running your app.

Or in Xcode, choose Product > Edit Scheme.  Then choose the Options tab.  From the iPhone Simulator Display popup menu, choose “Retina (3.5-inch)”.

Answer (score 4):

Delete the app from the Simulator, and do a Project menu Option-Clean in Xcode, after removing the tall Default png from the target, and before (re)building.